# p4 changes with specific path doesn't show any output

Tags: perforce

We are using Perforce and I need to list down all CL numbers from a specific depot path.

I have created my specific folder like as following //sw/test/Myname/project.

My understanding to get all the CL Numbers from //sw/test/Myname/project i have to use the following command:

p4 changes //sw/test/Myname/project

But this doesn't print anything in CMD line, but when I remove the specific path it works.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Sudheer

Answer (score 1):

The path:

```
//sw/test/Myname/project
```

matches a single file called `project` in the folder `//sw/test/Myname`.  If there is no such file, or if `project` is itself a folder, you'll get no results.

The command you probably want is:

```
p4 changes //sw/test/Myname/project/...
```

The `...` wildcard matches all files whose full path *starts with* `//sw/test/Myname/project/`, i.e. all files *underneath* that folder.

Comment: Thank you for your time and it worked as you suggested.